# Can not place Name, date signature in the declaration

Tags: formatting, minipage

In my declaration form, I like to write a latex minipage to include the Signature, Name, Registration Number , Place and Date at the bottom of the page. However, they are appearing in a scattered way.

```
 \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \large \textbf{Declaration}
\end{center}

I hereby declare that this dissertation is the product of my own work, and I attest that it contains no material that resulted from collaboration, except where explicitly acknowledged in the text. Furthermore, I confirm that this dissertation has not been previously submitted, either in part or in its entirety, to any other University or Institution for the purpose of obtaining any degree, diploma, or other qualification. All sources used and referenced in this dissertation are duly credited, and any borrowed ideas or information are appropriately cited in accordance with academic standards and guidelines.

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{5cm}}
    \dotfill & \dotfill \\
    Signature & Date \\
    & \\
    \dotfill & \dotfill \\
    Name & Place \\
    & \\
    \dotfill & \dotfill \\
    Registration Number &
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It is not mandatory to use minipage, any other approach ( like sub-figure or tabular or anything) that can give the desired output is welcome. Also the dotted lines may be removed and hard coded ( except the signature portion), if they look odd.

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu fonts on my system, so I can't compile your code. Please post an image of the result you get when you compile the code, and please state in detail what needs to be changed in that image.

Comment: Modified the code with \tabular, but things are scattered at the bottom. Need them at the right hand side at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You want that the `tabular` has the same width as the text block.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large \textbf{Declaration}
\end{center}

\noindent
I hereby declare that this dissertation is the product of my own work, 
and I attest that it contains no material that resulted from collaboration, 
except where explicitly acknowledged in the text. Furthermore, I confirm 
that this dissertation has not been previously submitted, either in part 
or in its entirety, to any other University or Institution for the purpose 
of obtaining any degree, diploma, or other qualification. All sources used 
and referenced in this dissertation are duly credited, and any borrowed 
ideas or information are appropriately cited in accordance with academic 
standards and guidelines.

\vspace{2cm}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}p{\dimexpr0.55\textwidth}
  @{\hspace{0.05\textwidth}}
  p{\dimexpr0.40\textwidth}@{}
}
    \dotfill & \dotfill \\
    Signature & Date \\
    & \\
    \dotfill & \dotfill \\
    Name & Place \\
    & \\
    \dotfill & \dotfill \\
    Registration Number &
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the `\noindent` to avoid the standard paragraph indentation.

[image]